# How to output raw html in an external js file

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

I have a scenario where i need to have raw html in an external js file.

the external js file takes care of initiating jquery ajax request and receiving the out put from ajax call and placing the received output in html . My presentation part is developed using Asp.net MVC. i am not sure which particular component is encoding the HTML, the MVC or JQuery or JSon. As it is external JS i am unable to use Razar methods like HMTL.RAW. I am thinking of using any JQuery helper which will work similar like HTML.Raw.

Regards,
Kumar.

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be in a JavaScript file, make it a giant string

```
var myCode = "<div>\
<span>foo</span>\
</div>\
<div id=\"bar\">aaaa</div>";
```

If the file is in the same domain, just make it a txt file or any type of file and read it with an Ajax request.